# typescript find in union in type map expression

Tags: typescript

Given

```
type A = { tag: 'Atag', A_id: 1 };
type B = { tag: 'Btag', B_id: 1 };
type C = { tag: 'Ctag', C_id: 1 };

type All = A | B | C;
```

I want `type AllByTag = Map<All>; /* { Atag: A; Btag: B; Ctag: C; } */`.

I tried this and it works good for one type, but when used with union I cant figure out how to narrow `T` to current iteration (it creates `{ Atag: All; Btag: All; Ctag: All; }`).

```
type $withTag = { tag: string; }
type Map<T extends $withTag> = {
  [P in T['tag']]: T
};
```

And this, but it can't infer `U` to something usable.

```
type Map<T extends $withTag> = {
  [P in T['tag']]: P extends T['tag'] ? infer U : never;
};
```

Comment: `Map` is an unfortunate name, since there is already [a `Map` type and value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in ambient scope.  Shadowing the built-in `Map` type with your own is probably not a great idea.

Comment: @jcalz A, B, C also not good names

Comment: Heh, I consider `A`, `B`, and `C` reasonable example type names (although they can be confused with type parameters), but `Map` can cause conflicts in an IDE unless you start using modules/namespaces.

Comment: @jcalz can you explain why my attempt with infer failed?

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax?  You can't put an `infer` there.

Comment: @jcalz I posted wrong snippet first, update the page. It's totally wrong nevertheless :.
I wanted to know why in `P extends T['tag'] ? infer U : never`
`U` is not `P` or `string` at least.

Comment: I mean, [it's invalid syntax](https://tsplay.dev/wXkj9W), so it doesn't work.  I'm not sure how else to explain it.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I had something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeVgEMDmAuKByG6GuANLAPoCWAJjgIxQC+A3ALABQokUAQgsqphy5uhEj0o0o9Zu07QAwnxSEh80aXkS6jVm1nhoMADZG+cAD48ol+bvb6uAEgDuFYAAsAKpiUDsUAGdgACcKADsMJkZ7DgMoAFkQeLQwAB5PKAgAD2AIMKoAqBc3L0wAPiV2KCgAbQAFKHCoTxrcUQBddpwG7Nz8wpa2zFx2qAB+RrCAMwhgqABVKBwwiAA3Wd0ZPW2Y3Z39vcOD46OjgDogA)

Comment:  You have a stray `.` at the bottom of the linked code, which is a separate syntax error. When you resolve that, you're left with the same code as before, with `infer U` in an invalid place, which is also an error. If you want to use [conditional type inference with `infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types), the `infer` clause can only show up within the `YYY` part of `XXX extends YYY ? AAA : BBB`; you are putting it in the `AAA` part, but this is invalid. It's not valid. Not. Valid. I hope we are on the same page now.

Comment: @jcalz hey. calm down. I just shown why i didn't get syntax error (because of another syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally (before TypeScript 4.1), you would have to compute the particular member of any union in `T` which corresponds to the one with the `P` tag.  You can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to do this:

```
type Map<T extends $withTag> = {
  [P in T['tag']]: Extract<T, { tag: P }>
};

type MappedAll = Map<All>;
/* type MappedAll = {
  Atag: A;
  Btag: B;
  Ctag: C;
} */
```

TypeScript 4.1 introduced [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) which allows you to represent the above more simply as:

```
type Map<T extends $withTag> = {
  [U in T as U['tag']]: U
};

type MappedAll = Map<All>;
/* type MappedAll = {
  Atag: A;
  Btag: B;
  Ctag: C;
} */
```

Here what you are doing is iterating the union `T` itself with `U`, and representing key `as U['tag']`; so on the property value side, you can just use `U` as the value.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVA5gCyQbwLACgCkkAXATxmQEEkBeHUkNALiQHIqSm2AaJKgPoBLACasAjEgC+AbiKkKyAEJ0GXFuyXreSJcLFJJs+eUpIAwquyMNbc9r7n9E6XML5ip6gBtvqmgA+ukhB5m4mikgAJADuQiQYACpMVjasUCQATkLAaDLSBIUeSKCQsAjIAOrxGACiAB5ZCCQ48p6RALIgMAA8iUgQjRDAIlDRcQnJaAB8Vm3ESADaAApIOUiJi2zaALo7rA1N8CR9fNbqrKtS0-PG7gsKZl0wlCJUvqrPPe-e024PAHoAFSPZDPV4-ObFB6cJisKj-B66C66REPexwixo6RIIEA+RSIrEUrQOCIJDVBIAJQgYG6MByaFa9wWXiQX36gxIw1G4xqU1m9Dw0IWixQa2AGyQIDGKC2u32qFu4RFbPBEDeH3oXx+f3mwNB7PpGshQvmxFhGgR5uRmKU2OIGI0YVuuPx7gJRSKUiAA)